# Proportional Proof

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> **Question:** How would you prove this theorem:

---

> If $$\frac ab=\frac cd=\frac ef=\&c\tag1$$
>   Then$$\frac ab=\frac {a+c+e+\&c}{b+d+f+\&c}\tag{2}$$

And using that proof, is it possible to prove the following generalized theorem:

> **General Formula:** If $\frac ab=\frac cd=\frac ef=\&c=k$, then we have $k$ as$$k=\frac {pa^n+qc^n+re^n+\&c}{pb^n+qd^n+rf^n+\&c}^{\frac 1n}\tag3$$
>   For $p,q,r,\&c$ are any quantities.

---

I know about *compenendo et dividendo* where if $\frac ab=\frac cd$, then $\frac {a+b}{a-b}=\frac {c+d}{c-d}$. But I'm not too sure if that will help with proving both formulae.

Basically, I'm not sure where to even begin and what techniques I should employ. Anything is appreciated!

Comment: Hint (using $\lambda$ instead of `&c`): substitute $\;a = \lambda b, c = \lambda d, \dots\;$.

Comment: What is $n$? Is it any natural number?

Comment: @Siddhant I'm guessing $n$ is a random natural number... The book never said so... :/

Comment: Indeed, if the second formula is true, its beautiful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either have a typo or that is **very** false:

Let $a = c = e = \lambda = 2$ and $b = d = f = 1$.

Then you have $$\frac ab=\frac {a+c+e+\lambda}{b+d+f+\lambda} \iff \frac 21=\frac {2+2+2+2}{1+1+1+2} \iff 2 = \frac85$$

Assuming you didn't mean to put the $\lambda$ there, thus having

$$\frac ab=\frac {a+c+e}{b+d+f}$$ you can follow the hint in the comments and set

$$\begin{cases} a = \lambda b\\c = \lambda d\\ e = \lambda f\end{cases}$$

and have:

$$\lambda=\frac {\lambda b + \lambda d + \lambda f}{b+d+f} \iff \lambda = \lambda \frac {b + d + f}{b+d+f} \iff \lambda = \lambda$$

Similarly, with the same substitutions we can have

$$\lambda=\frac {p(\lambda b)^n+q(\lambda d)^n+r(\lambda f)^n}{pb^n+qd^n+rf^n}^{\frac 1n} \iff \lambda = ((\lambda)^n\frac {pb^n+qd^n+rf^n}{pb^n+qd^n+rf^n})^{\frac 1n} \iff \lambda = {\lambda^n}^\frac1n$$

Comment: Indeed. @Frank The `&c` in the denominator of $(2)$ should be $1$ instead, since the fraction which is equal to the others is $\frac{\&c}{1}$.

Comment: @dxiv Hm... do you think $\&c$ *could* mean infinitely others? Like $$\frac ab=\frac {a+c+e\ldots}{b+d+f\ldots}$$

Comment: @Frank If you mean several others (*not* infinitely many) then use $a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n$. I've never seen `&c` used that way (in math). Plus, $(3)$ says that `&c` is a `quantity`.

Comment: @Frank either way if that is the meaning of &c, the proof remains essentially the same and is still valid.

Answer (score 0):

Just another way:

> We have a theorem where given $\frac ab=\frac cd=\frac ef=\ldots=k$, we can write it as$$k=\frac {a+c+e\ldots}{b+d+f\ldots}\tag1$$

We can multiply the numerator and denominators by $p,q,r\ldots$ to keep the fraction the same and raise everything the $n$ power. Thus, we now have $(1)$ as$$k^n=\frac {pa^n+qc^n+re^n+\ldots}{pb^n+qd^n+rf^n+\ldots}\tag{2}$$
And taking the $n^{\text{th}}$ root, gives us $(3)$.